# Resolving Controllers via routes for imported Play 2.4.x project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to import any Play project (usually from activator) into *IntelliJ* and each time I end up with Controllers not being resolved, i.e. you go to `conf/routes` and `routes.ApplicationController` shows up red and inside any Controller completion for `routes.` shows no controllers.

The projects do compile in, and even run from *IntelliJ*, but compiled routes just aren't picked up.

I don't know if it's related, but on project load I always get the following message:

> SBT compilation for play framework 2.x disabled by default

But even if I go into the *Languages & Frameworks* setup and tell it to use the Play 2 compiler, the routes are not affected.

Comment: are you trying importing from directly IntelliJ or using activator to create project files? With the lastest version of IntelliJ you can directly import scala/play projects created by activator, no need to do anything if you have plugins

Comment: I'm importing directly. I've also tried using the activator project generation, but that's even worse, and IntelliJ actively tells you not to do that anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hüseyin Zengin is right. The activator plugin which generates the .idea directory and metadata is no longer 'the way'.

The truth is it doesn't work perfectly out of the box and your best bet is to get on the latest versions of all three. This means using the Early Access Program version of Intellij.

This largely depends on the versions of Play!, Intellij and the Scala (formerly Play) plugin.

If you can't do that or still get the problem anyway then following these steps might help:

Open your Play! 2.x project in Intellij
Open Module Settings F4
In the *Root* Source Settings navigate the directory structure.

Add the *main* directory at

target/scala-/routes/main

to the Source Folders list. Right clicking the main folder and selecting Sources is one way to do this.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. The only one that would work properly was upgrading to latest EAP of IntelliJ and Scala plug-in. At least it works now